# CSOM: How to get user groups specific to a site and not all the user groups in the site collection?

Tags: client-object-model

I am trying to get the list of user groups specific to a site (`within a site collection`) but the `Web.SiteGroups` is returning all the user groups at the site collection level, and therefore I am unable to determine which group has permissions to a specific site.

I need help in below points.

1. Understand the concept/relationship between the site collection(all sites in the collection) and user groups?
2. Specific to a site get all the user groups that have some permission to the site and exclude groups that do not have permission to a site/
   code is included.

Below is the code:

```
public static void GetSiteUsers(ClientContext ctx, Web mySite, StringBuilder sb)
    {
        //to retrieve master site groups
        //ctx.Load(mySite.SiteGroups);
        //ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        GroupCollection oSiteCollectionGroups = mySite.SiteGroups; //KT:9-3-15 to limit groups to this site
        //GroupCollection oSiteCollectionGroups = ctx.Web.SiteGroups;
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------Groups in Site--------------------");
        Console.WriteLine(mySite.Title + " List of groups in the site collection");
        sb.AppendLine("-----------------Groups in Site--------------------");
        sb.AppendLine(mySite.Title + " List of groups in the site collection");

        ctx.Load(oSiteCollectionGroups);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();


        foreach (Group oGroup in oSiteCollectionGroups)
        {
    ***//Unfortunately the oSiteCollectionGroup contains groups from the parent site, as well as the child sites***
            //Console.WriteLine(mySite.Title + " Group :" + oGroup.Title + " id = " + oGroup.Id);
            //sb.AppendLine(mySite.Title + " Group :" + oGroup.Title + " id = " + oGroup.Id);
            ////Console.WriteLine(" Group Description:" + oGroup.Description);
            try
            {
                UserCollection usercollection = oGroup.Users;
                ctx.Load(usercollection);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (User oUser in usercollection)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(mySite.Title + " Group :" + oGroup.Title + " User: " + oUser.LoginName);
                    string[] loginNameParts = oUser.LoginName.Split('|');


                    sb.AppendLine(mySite.ServerRelativeUrl + "," + oGroup.Title + "," + oGroup.Context + "," + loginNameParts[2] + "," + oUser.Email);
                    //sb.AppendLine(web.Title + "," + oUser.LoginName + "," + oGroup.Title);
                }
            }
            catch
           {
                //Console.WriteLine("Site : " + mySite.Title + " Group :" + oGroup.Title + " Group ID:" + oGroup.Id + " User: No Access ");
                //sb.AppendLine("Site : " + web.Title + " Group :" + oGroup.Title + " User: No Access ");
                //sb.AppendLine(web.Title + "," + "No Access to User" + "," + oGroup.Title);
            }


        }


    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is how to do it in JS

```
 var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
 var web = clientContext.get_web();
 var webGroupsCollection = web.get_roleAssignments().get_groups(); //gets a  web specific groups
 var siteGroupsCollection = web.get_siteGroups(); //gets all site collection’s groups
```

similarly there would be something like `Web.RoleAssignments.Groups` in C# object model

Comment: How do we do this in PowerShell ?